# MVC 5 How create clickable <tr> row to reconnect to customer edit with id from table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onclick, actionlink, tr

I need to enable click on the row of table to reconnect to customer edit view , I need customer id. `@*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=customer.CustomerId })`

Customer View List:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@customer.Name</td>
            <td>@customer.Surname</td>
         </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You haven't demonstrated what you have tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add the attribute `onclick` on your tr tag like  this :

```
  <tr onclick="location.href = '@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=customer.CustomerId }))'">
    <td>@customer.Name</td>
    <td>@customer.Surname</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thx, its great!

Comment: Correct: <tr onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { id=customer.CustomerId })'">

Comment: Can anyone also suggest how to change the clickable row css onmouse hover please

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this like the below.

Use css to use as a JQuery selector, obtain the id from the data attribute and then use window.opener passing in the customer id.

**CSS Style**

```
.ClickToEdit {
}
```

**View HTML with data-customerid attribute set from model**

Class is set on the row.

```
 <tr class="ClickToEdit" data-customerid="@customer.CustomerId">
   <td>
      @customer.Name
    </td>
 </tr>
```

**JQuery to intercept click and open URL**

```
$(document).on("click", ".ClickToEdit", function () {
    var custID = $(this).data("customerid"); 
    window.opener.location.href("/Edit/Edit?id=" + custID);
});
```

Hope that helps